# Any one Suggest how to send push notification of upcoming event, my database is firebase real time database

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have database of firebase realtime with event now i want if any upcoming event in tomorrow then user will notify for that event.

Comment: event meanss?? if today any event is there you want to send a mail to users that event is there today?

Comment: if today any event then user get push notification yesterday for this notification.

Comment: you can go to this link  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule   and you can execute the script daily by using cron..hope this helps

Comment: Did above link helped something?